# Angular 2 Http Post Set Content-Length header to 0

Tags: angular, post

I need to make a POST call with a content-length equal to 0. So I tried setting the header to 0 when I make the call but in the web service that receives the call the content-length is much greater than 0.

**Request**

```
let url = '/blah/blah/'+ anUID +'/blah/' + anotherUID + '';
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Length': '0'});
let options = new RequestOptions({
  method: RequestMethod.Post,
  headers: headers,
});

return this.http.post(url, options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

The on in the receiving web service there is a check to make sure that the request's content length is 0.

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("{anUID}/blah/{anotherUID}")
public Response myWebService(@PathParam("anUID") Integer anUID, @PathParam("anotherUID") Integer anotherUID,
        @Context ServletContext application, @Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context UriInfo info) {
    Response resp = Response.notModified().build();
    String method = request.getMethod();    // == "POST"
    int meh = request.getContentLength();   // = 172 NEEDS TO BE 0

    if (request.getContentLength() < 1) {
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

What could I do differently to set the content-length equal to 0?

Comment: What is the purpose of making the content length as 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set header. Just send empty body will do.

```
return this.http.post(url, '')
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```